# Why does ANSIBLE require no database?

Tags: database, ansible

I have been using ansible for a couple of weeks now and while browsing through the ANSIBLE docs on http://docs.ansible.com, I came across the Database Modules like MySQL, POSTGRESQL, etc. I've been hearing that ANSIBLE doesn't require any database. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible does not require a database or even any server processes. The [database modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_database_modules.html) you found are intended for Ansible to *manage* databases, e.g. create a MySQL database or create a new database user.

Comment: Maybe add Ansible uses mainly yaml files as datastore that are loaded at run time rather than a full database/dbms.